# Not able to use custom layout in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, xml

I'm new to android, I want to use my custom layout file instead of simple_list_item_1 but its not allowing to do so. I want to add an backgroud image(which is defined in layout->custom_view.xml) to each items in the list OR help me to set the backgroud for the whole page, In the below code where should I use the setContentView Method. Also let me know if any changes are to be made in the below .xml file.

```
public class Planet extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.custom_view); Tried to set the view from here but the application is crashing...
    String[] planet_names = new String[] {"Mercury","Venus","Earth","Mars","Jupiter","Saturn","Uranus","Neptune","Sun"};
                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, planet_names);
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                        ListView lv = getListView();
                        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                                if(position == 0)
                                {
                                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Planet.this, Galaxy.class);
                                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

                            }

                }
                });
                }
```

custom_view.xml file is as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"> 

         <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />     
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use this

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.yourcustomview_withonetextview,R.id.yourcustomlayouttextviewid, planet_names);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the contentview in a `ListActivity`. The `ListActivity` already does that for you.  Use an `Activity`, if you want to customize your layout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `super.onCreate()` before `setContentView()`. And if you are going to use a custom layout in a ListActivity, you need to give the ListView the id `@android:id/list`.